# Replace All not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.1) and I am trying to use `Replace All` to replace text in all files within the project:

[image]

This function simply doesn't work (just says 0 occurrences replace). I am within the current project.

However when I use just `Replace` it works as expected albeit single replacements.

Any workaround to the `Replace All` functionality?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I am also using 17.5 Preview 1.  I assume you also meant to have "Match Case" enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the area where you do the search and replacement.
Here in the picture you can see that the scope is set to "Current project" which means the replacement **will not be done** in the files that are **out** of the current project:

[image]

To fix the issue, just click on the "Current project" and change it to either "Entire solution" or "All open documents".

Comment: I want to perform a replace all on all files (even closed documents) within the current project (and not the entire solution). This option used to work before.